# ROS2 Humble colcon tutorial causes flake8 error

Tags: ros2, python, ros-humble, colcon

I was working on this colcon tutorial and got the following error in the ["Build the workspace" section](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Colcon-Tutorial.html#build-the-workspace):

```
Warning: SelectableGroups dict interface is deprecated. Use select.
```

This seems to be the error that flask8 is giving, and probably the flask8 in the cloned repository is the cause of the error.
However, I cannot think of any concrete means to eliminate this error. How can I fix this error?

---

Here is a full log:

```
$ colcon test
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_async_client
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_cbg_executor
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_client
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_server
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_minimal_client
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_minimal_composition
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher                              
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_minimal_service
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_minimal_subscriber
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_minimal_timer
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_multithreaded_executor
Starting >>> examples_rclcpp_wait_set
Starting >>> examples_rclpy_executors                                        
Starting >>> examples_rclpy_guard_conditions
Starting >>> examples_rclpy_minimal_action_client
Starting >>> examples_rclpy_minimal_action_server
Starting >>> examples_rclpy_minimal_client
Starting >>> examples_rclpy_minimal_publisher
Starting >>> examples_rclpy_minimal_service                                  
Starting >>> examples_rclpy_minimal_subscriber
Starting >>> examples_rclpy_pointcloud_publisher
Starting >>> launch_testing_examples
--- stderr: examples_rclpy_minimal_action_server                             

=============================== warnings summary ===============================
actions/minimal_action_server/test/test_flake8.py::test_flake8
actions/minimal_action_server/test/test_flake8.py::test_flake8
  Warning: SelectableGroups dict interface is deprecated. Use select.

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/warnings.html
---
Finished <<< examples_rclpy_minimal_action_server [1.34s]
--- stderr: examples_rclpy_guard_conditions

=============================== warnings summary ===============================
guard_conditions/test/test_flake8.py::test_flake8
guard_conditions/test/test_flake8.py::test_flake8
  Warning: SelectableGroups dict interface is deprecated. Use select.

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/warnings.html
---
Finished <<< examples_rclpy_guard_conditions [1.37s]
--- stderr: examples_rclpy_minimal_publisher

=============================== warnings summary ===============================
topics/minimal_publisher/test/test_flake8.py::test_flake8
topics/minimal_publisher/test/test_flake8.py::test_flake8
  Warning: SelectableGroups dict interface is deprecated. Use select.

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/warnings.html
---
Finished <<< examples_rclpy_minimal_publisher [1.31s]
--- stderr: examples_rclpy_executors

=============================== warnings summary ===============================
executors/test/test_flake8.py::test_flake8
executors/test/test_flake8.py::test_flake8
  Warning: SelectableGroups dict interface is deprecated. Use select.

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/warnings.html
---
Finished <<< examples_rclpy_executors [1.39s]
--- stderr: examples_rclpy_minimal_client

=============================== warnings summary ===============================
services/minimal_client/test/test_flake8.py::test_flake8
services/minimal_client/test/test_flake8.py::test_flake8
  Warning: SelectableGroups dict interface is deprecated. Use select.

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/warnings.html
---
Finished <<< examples_rclpy_minimal_client [1.33s]
--- stderr: examples_rclpy_minimal_action_client

=============================== warnings summary ===============================
actions/minimal_action_client/test/test_flake8.py::test_flake8
actions/minimal_action_client/test/test_flake8.py::test_flake8
  Warning: SelectableGroups dict interface is deprecated. Use select.

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/warnings.html
---
Finished <<< examples_rclpy_minimal_action_client [1.36s]
--- stderr: examples_rclpy_minimal_service                                   

=============================== warnings summary ===============================
services/minimal_service/test/test_flake8.py::test_flake8
services/minimal_service/test/test_flake8.py::test_flake8
  Warning: SelectableGroups dict interface is deprecated. Use select.

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/warnings.html
---
Finished <<< examples_rclpy_minimal_service [1.32s]
--- stderr: examples_rclpy_minimal_subscriber                                

=============================== warnings summary ===============================
topics/minimal_subscriber/test/test_flake8.py::test_flake8
topics/minimal_subscriber/test/test_flake8.py::test_flake8
  Warning: SelectableGroups dict interface is deprecated. Use select.

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/warnings.html
---
Finished <<< examples_rclpy_minimal_subscriber [1.40s]
--- stderr: examples_rclpy_pointcloud_publisher                              

=============================== warnings summary ===============================
topics/pointcloud_publisher/test/test_flake8.py::test_flake8
topics/pointcloud_publisher/test/test_flake8.py::test_flake8
  Warning: SelectableGroups dict interface is deprecated. Use select.

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/warnings.html
---
Finished <<< examples_rclpy_pointcloud_publisher [1.55s]
Finished <<< examples_rclcpp_wait_set [4.00s]                                
Finished <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_composition [4.11s]
Finished <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher [4.10s]                        
Finished <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_subscriber [4.07s]
Finished <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_client [4.14s]
Finished <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_server [4.16s]
Finished <<< examples_rclcpp_cbg_executor [4.21s]
Finished <<< examples_rclcpp_async_client [4.22s]
Finished <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_timer [4.07s]
Finished <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_action_client [4.19s]
Finished <<< examples_rclcpp_multithreaded_executor [4.05s]
Finished <<< examples_rclcpp_minimal_service [4.10s]
--- stderr: launch_testing_examples                       

=============================== warnings summary ===============================
test/test_flake8.py::test_flake8
test/test_flake8.py::test_flake8
  Warning: SelectableGroups dict interface is deprecated. Use select.

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/warnings.html
---
Finished <<< launch_testing_examples [17.4s]

Summary: 22 packages finished [18.1s]
  10 packages had stderr output: examples_rclpy_executors examples_rclpy_guard_conditions examples_rclpy_minimal_action_client examples_rclpy_minimal_action_server examples_rclpy_minimal_client examples_rclpy_minimal_publisher examples_rclpy_minimal_service examples_rclpy_minimal_subscriber examples_rclpy_pointcloud_publisher launch_testing_examples
```

---

Here is my computer environment:

- Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
- Python 3.10.12
- I installed ros-humble-desktop of version 0.10.0-1jammy.20231207.082253 following the tutorial [here](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation.html)

Answer (score 0):

A deprecation warning is typically not a fatal error, and the current code still functions correctly. What it is telling you is that this code may stop working in the next release.

To be clear: I'm describing a general rule, but don't know the story with this **exact** warning message.

The fix is to change the source code to not use the obsolete feature. Obviously you will need to understand the source code at least a little to do this.